# If $\int_{-2}^{x}f(t)dt=x^2\sin(\pi x)$ and $f(\pi/3)=\frac{\pi}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$, what is the value of $\frac{a}{b^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

**Problem:** If $\int_{-2}^{x}f(t)dt=x^2\sin(\pi x)$ and $f(\pi/3)=\frac{\pi}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$, what is the value of $\frac{a}{b^2}$?

**My approach:** Applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have that $$f(x) = 2x\sin(\pi x) + \pi x^2\cos(\pi x).$$ Then, $$\frac{\pi}{a}+\frac{1}{b} = f(\pi/3) = \frac{2\pi}{3}\sin\left(\frac{\pi^2}{3}\right) + \frac{\pi^3}{9}\cos\left(\frac{\pi^2}{3}\right).$$

However, I don't see how to continue. Can you give me some advice to get the result?

Comment: They certainly meant $f(1/3)$. And they certainly meant $a,b\in\overline{\Bbb Q}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But in that case, wouldn't the value of $b$ be equal to $\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the last edit. What do you mean with $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Comment: I agree with the others, it makes sense that there is an extra $\pi$ where there should not be one.

Comment: Graphically you can get a good approximation giving $a=-1.03$ and $b=-1.5$

Comment: $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the set of algebraic numbers, which does include $\sqrt{3}$. This just seems like a poorly written question.